# Recursively Remove Line of Code In Files Residing In Directory And Deeply Nested Directories

Tags: bash, unix

I would like to find out how, using a bash command/script, would I remove certain lines of code in files that end with a certain extension and are within directories and (deeply-nested) sub-directories?

Essentially I would like to remove any line of code that starts with `import` and ends with `"(some file name here).scss"`

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -exec sed --in-place 's/^import.*.sccs$//g' {} \;
```

Comment: I get `sed: illegal option -- -` when I run this. Prolly `--in-place` should be `-in-place`?

Comment: @brandNew this assumes GNU `sed` which has `--in-place` arg. What OS you are using?

Comment: I am running MacOS High Sierra. When I run it with flag `-in-place`, It says `sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence` and then appends `-place` to filenames.

Comment: Can you paste `sed --version` output?

Comment: Can't run that command. It gives me the same error as in my first comment

Comment: @brandNew I think this might apply: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/248113/how-to-install-gnu-sed
then use gsed instead of sed

Comment: Oh yeah, well that executed but seemingly could not find file/directory. That is the error I am getting.

Comment: What's the error? Do you run it in the root of directories you want to process?

Comment: Error is `find: gsed: No such file or directory` and yes I amm running the command at root level. Even when I `cd` to `src/components` and run the command like `find ./ -type f -exec gsed --in-place 's/^import.*.sccs$//g' {} \;` I get the same error.

Comment: Can you use the option `-i` instead of the long form `--in-place`?

Comment: I ge the same error as in my previous comment. No such file or directory

Comment: @brandNew you need to install GNU sed on your system

Comment: gsed is the gnu one, isn't it?

Comment: @brandNew yes, but I don't think you have it installed, judging from the find output

Comment: Oh yeah, seems like I didn't have it. The command executed now, but still no import has been removed. Git diff is empty. And I can see the imports

Comment: @brandNew Maybe it's something related to `find` on MacOS, I'm afraid I can't guide you further.
Are you sure you don't have Windows line endings and/or trailing/leading whitespace in those lines?

Comment: No, it's LF not CRLF

Comment: I meant using `sed -i` - you already have a `sed` so shouldn't need to install the GNU one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have perl,

```
find . -type f -name '*.extension' |
xargs perl -pi.bak -e 's/^import.*\.sccs.*//'
```

This replaces each matching import statement with an empty line and keeps backups named `filename.bak` just in case. If you don't want backups, drop the `.bak` part from the perl statement.

Comment: This command is executed but nothing is being removed. And that is with or without the `.bak` part

Comment: @brandNew Maybe the anchoring is too strict. Is there really no white space at the start of the line, i.e. is "import" at the very beginning? You did change `extension` to the particular extension you want, say `*.py` for python files?